# JQuery mobile popup $.mobile.changePage Bug?

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

The popup seems to be really buggy (not release ready). The popups close event will fire if it is closed (as it is supposed to do)..but ALSO when you switch to another page (multi page layout). This should not happen at all. Because you might never have opened the popup...but still the close event is fired when you switch page (how did they miss that one?).

Also, From a popup´s close event i try to return to the previous page by using $.mobile.changePage(../schedule.html); But if i do this in my popup´s close event very strange things happens. So this code:

```
$( "#somepage #popupstatus" ).bind({
    popupafterclose: function(event, ui) 
    {
        console.log('closing popup');
        if (isPopupVisible)
        {
            isPopupVisible=false;
            //do stuff
            $.mobile.changePage('../schedule.html');
        }       
    }
});
```

Will make you jump back to previous page...then it will jump to this page again.
Why? Is this another bug? Have anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar issue where I had a confirm button on a popup. I figured I needed to close the popup before I changed the page. Apparently just changing the page will close the popup as well. I went from:

```
$('#confirm_status').popup('close');
self.loadWorkOrders();
$.mobile.changePage('#work_orders');
```

to:

```
self.loadWorkOrders();
$.mobile.changePage('#work_orders');
```

and now it is working correctly.

Comment: Had the same issue, removed the .popup("close") method and it started working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing similar issues.

Page 1 (list page) transitions to Page 2 (detail page), where the popup is opened after the user clicks a button and a successful Ajax-POST is done. When closing the popup a changePage to Page 1 is issued. This caused the popupafterclose event to fire when going to Page 2 again.

Preventing this using a simple boolean check in said event (set to true when POST is issued, set to false when the popup is opened) lead to other weird behaviour - the initial transition from Page 1 to Page 2 was nearly always re-executed, so the user would always see two transitions: the intended one to Page 1 after the popup closed, directly afterwards the one from Page 1 to Page 2 again.

At this point I just gave up, I'll be trying to use a dialog instead of a popup.

Comment: I figuered out a way to solve it. Use a boolean, as you said. Mine is called "isPopupVisible. Then if it is true then use a short timeout (1 millisecond) and the go back to prev page. It works, a hack until a fix has been made.